# Python encode spaces in url only and not other special characters

Tags: python

I know this question has been asked many times but I can't seem to find the variation that I'm looking for specifically.

I have a url, lets say its:

```
https://somethingA/somethingB/somethingC/some spaces here
```

I want to convert it to:

```
https://somethingA/somethingB/somethingC/some%20spaces%20here
```

I know I can do it with the `replace` function like below:

```
url = https://somethingA/somethingB/somethingC/some spaces here
url.replace(' ', '%20')
```

But I have a feeling that the best practice is probably to use the `urllib.parse` library. The problem is that when I use it, it encodes other special characters like `:` too.

So if I do:

```
url = https://somethingA/somethingB/somethingC/some spaces here
urllib.parse.quote(url)
```

I get:

```
https%3A//somethingA/somethingB/somethingC/some%20spaces%20here
```

Notice the `:` also gets converted to `%3A`. So my question is, is there a way I can achieve the same thing as replace with `urllib`? I think I would rather use a tried and tested library that is designed specifically to encode URLs instead of reinventing the wheel, which I may or may not be missing something leading to a security loop hole. Thank you.

Comment: Separate the http/https part from your URL and do it just for the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `quote()` there is built to work on just the path portion of a url.  So you need to break things up a bit like this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = 'https://somethingA/somethingB/somethingC/some spaces here'
parts = urlparse(url)
fixed_url = f"{parts.scheme}://{parts.netloc}/{urllib.parse.quote(parts.path)}"
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about urlparse